# how to change color of textspan in flutter from left to right with animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

[animation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChC7m.png)

I have tried to use colorTween but it changes the whole word I want to change the color from left to right with different like the image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `ShaderMask`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: LoadingText(
            'Loading... Please wait!',
            .5,
            fontSize: 25,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoadingText extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingText(
    this.text,
    this.progress, {
    this.progressColor = Colors.blue,
    this.textColor = Colors.red,
    this.fontSize,
  });

  final String text;
  /// Must be 0 to 1.
  final double progress;
  final Color progressColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final double fontSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) => LinearGradient(
        colors: <Color>[progressColor, textColor],
        stops: <double>[progress, progress],
      ).createShader(bounds),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: fontSize,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```